# Own Iterator for generic Pair class

Tags: java, generics, iterator

I am trying to write my **own Iterator** for my own generic class. I have been watching several YouTube tutorials and searching the web.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Pair<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private T left;
    private T right;

    public Pair(T left, T right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public  T getRight(){return this.right;}
    public  T getLeft(){return this.left;}

    // own Iterator
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new myIterator;
    }


    class myIterator implements Iterator<T>{
        T newLeft = null;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(newLeft == null && Pair.getLeft() != null){
                return true;
            }
            else if(newLeft !=null){
                return Pair.getRight() !=null;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public T next() {
            if(newLeft == null && Pair.getLeft() != null){
                newLeft = Pair.getLeft();
                return newLeft;
            }
            else if(newLeft != null){
                T newRight = Pair.getLeft();
                newLeft = Pair.getRight();
                return newRight;
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem pointed out by IntelliJ is, that I cannot use getLeft and getRight in the Iterator-Class the way I am trying to, since the **non-static methods cannot be referenced from a static context**. I have been digging into static and a lot more, but could not solve this problem. Am I fully on the wrong track, or is my approach somewhat close, at least?

## UPDATE

When running:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair<Integer> intPair= new Pair(5,1);
        Pair<String> stringPair=new Pair("foo", "bar");

        Iterator<Integer> itr= intPair.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
```

I encounter an endless loop, printing 5. So, Iterator itself works, but my methods have a logical error. Working on it, but I am thankful for any input. :)

## UPDATE2

Logical erro found: NewLeft never is changed from being null. Working to resolve it.

## UPDATE3

: Solved!
Full Pair-Class with embedded Iterator-Class and main class with calls below:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Pair<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private T left;
    private T right;

    public Pair(T left, T right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public  T getRight(){return this.right;}
    public  T getLeft(){return this.left;}

    // size of a pair is always 2
    public int size =2;

    // own Iterator
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new myIterator();
    }

    // embedded iterator class
    public class myIterator implements Iterator<T>{
        T newLeft = null;
        T newRight = null;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(newLeft == null && getLeft() != null){
                return true;
            }
            else if(newLeft !=null && newRight == null){
                newRight=getRight();
                return getRight() !=null;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public T next() {
            if(newLeft == null && getLeft() != null){
                newLeft = getLeft();
                return newLeft;
            }
            else if(newLeft != null && getRight() != null){
                newRight = getRight();
                return newRight;
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair<Integer> intPair= new Pair(5,1);
        Pair<String> stringPair=new Pair("foo", "bar");

        Iterator<Integer> itr= intPair.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }

        Iterator<String> itrS= stringPair.iterator();
        while(itrS.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itrS.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everybody, who helped, you led me to this solution :)

Comment: It looks like you need to change `Pair.getLeft()` to `getLeft()` and `Pair.getRight()` to `getRight()`

Comment: Much easier: `return Arrays.asList(left, right).iterator();`.

Comment: @AndyTurner not exactly, since that doesn't handle the case of getRight() or getLeft() returning null.

Comment: @Eran ok, so create a list without the nulls, and return its iterator. `Stream.of(left, right).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(toList()).iterator()`.

Comment: @Eran, thanks, it worked, errors are gone. currently testing

Comment: so, the iterator works, but I must have a mistake in the interator's methods (see update in question, but I will work on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial code is defining a variable `T newLeft` whose only purpose is to track whether the left value has been consumed, indicated by a non-`null` value. It would be much clearer to use a `boolean` variable, i.e. `boolean hasSeenLeft;` here. Then, it would become obvious that this class is incomplete, as it doesn’t track whether the right value has been consumed.

In your fixed code, you have `newLeft` and `newRight`, which solves the issue, but still is misleading, as neither their names nor their type do indicate the actual purpose. If you change them to `boolean` variables, you could design them to indicate whether there are pending values, e.g.

```
final class myIterator implements Iterator<T> { // no need to make this public
    boolean hasPendingLeft = getLeft() != null, hasPendingRight = getRight() != null;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasPendingLeft || hasPendingRight;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if(hasPendingLeft) {
            hasPendingLeft = false;
            return getLeft();
        }
        else if(hasPendingRight) {
            hasPendingRight = false;
            return getRight();
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

which is much simpler and more readable.

Note that neither solution can handle in-between changes, but this `Pair` class looks like it should be immutable in the best case anyway. In that case, it’s worth declaring `left` and `right` as `final`.

For a mutable class, it would be worth adding a fail-fast behavior for in-between modifications, similar to the Collection API:

```
final class myIterator implements Iterator<T> { // no need to make this public
    boolean hasPendingLeft = getLeft() != null, hasPendingRight = getRight() != null;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasPendingLeft || hasPendingRight;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if(hasPendingLeft) {
            hasPendingLeft = false;
            T left = getLeft();
            if(left == null) throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            return left;
        }
        else if(hasPendingRight) {
            hasPendingRight = false;
            T right = getRight();
            if(right == null) throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            return right;
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

So this still guarantees non-`null` values even in the erroneous case and will throw a more meaningful exception then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to iterate over the 0 to 2 possible values in this pair? In your iterator you should be referring to the instances of T. The message you're getting is because you're trying to call a method in Pair in a static way (i.e. you're calling Pair.getLeft() when Pair is the class)

Comment: so, I understand my "static/non-static error", thanks :) as suggested from @Eran, I changed Pair.getLeft() etc. to getLeft() only. Am I getting it right, that this is referring to the instances?

Comment: @Shushiro I don't have any experience implementing an Iterator and how it gets an instance of your Pair class, but I suppose that should do the trick. Perhaps just see if it works?

Comment: von den Broek. currently doing so :) at least it is somewhat logic. The causative agent for the static/non-static problem (Pair) is gone, and getLeft() and getRight() return this.left/this.right, which is from my Pair and then should be, what I want? I hope so, currently testing :)

Comment: Iterator is working, but I have at least one logical error in my itertor's methods